# GPIO pins on a RPI3 on Arch

Tags: pi-3, gpio

I have a RPI3 with Arch on it and I cannot access any of the GPIO pins.

When using a python wrapper like gpiozero to turn a pin on I get an error like:

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:451: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from rpigpio: This module can only be run on a Raspberry Pi!
  'Falling back from %s: %s' % (name, str(e))))
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:451: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from rpio: No module named 'RPIO'
  'Falling back from %s: %s' % (name, str(e))))
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:451: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from pigpio: No module named 'pigpio'
  'Falling back from %s: %s' % (name, str(e))))
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:451: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from native: unable to open /dev/gpiomem or /dev/mem; upgrade your kernel or run as root
  'Falling back from %s: %s' % (name, str(e))))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./lampon", line 2, in <module>
    from gpiozero import LED
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpiozero/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .devices import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 480, in <module>
    Device.pin_factory = _default_pin_factory()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 452, in _default_pin_factory
    raise BadPinFactory('Unable to load any default pin factory!')
gpiozero.exc.BadPinFactory: Unable to load any default pin factory!
```

Other libraries give the same result.

I believe the problem is in fact deeper and has to do with the fact that the device tree does not include the pins, my folder

```
/sys/class/gpio/
```

does not contain any pin device/file and so I can't write to their status by echoing.

I've tried loading the device tree from a previous RPI by adding

```
device_tree=bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
```

to config.txt (and downloading the file) which prevented the pi from booting. I also tried adding

```
dtparam=gpio_out_pin=2
```

Any suggestion? I can't believe the pin don't work on the RPI3 period...

Answer (score 1):

You really need to ask on an Arch specific forum.

Arch is a distribution targeted at experts.

gpiozero and the other modules may be complaining because they need the device `/dev/gpiomem`, and a `gpio` group, and for the pi user to be a member of the `gpio` group.

Try my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/).  It might work on Arch.

Comment: I will give it a try. But the arch arm forum are a bit dead as it seems. But this seems a larger issue w/ device tree. Does the basic raspbian installation show the gpio under /dev/ ? I might try steal that tree or just flash raspian back

Comment: I think `/devgpiomem` (for rootless access to GPIO) was added by raspberrypi.org for Raspbian (which is their preferred operating system).